# exporting table into ms word PHP & MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, ms-word

I am trying to export specific things into a word document from ms sql table ,

but when I edit my HTML code it does not export any information but when I write all the values it works, I basically want to output the following only! (Impact, Return_Year2  Return_Year3    Return_Year4    Return_Year5 )

Code I have done so far

```
$dbQuery = sqlsrv_query($db, "select * from vw_Impact_Return2 ");
  $rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbQuery);

    //print('<pre>');
    //print_r($rows); 
    //print('<pre>');
    //exit;

while($dbRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbQuery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Schema_ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Stakeholder_ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Intended_Changes']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Investment_Type_ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Value_of_Investment']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Summary']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Description']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Indicator']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Source']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Quantity']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Duration']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Start']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Financial_Proxy']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Deadweight']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Displacement']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Attribution']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Drop_Off']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Impact']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year0']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year1']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year2']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year3']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year4']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $dbRow['Return_Year5']; ?></td>

    </tr>
<?php

  }

} // end of function databaseOutput()

if (isset($_POST['submit_docs'])) { // word output

  header("Content-Type:application/msword");
  header("Expires: 0");
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=test.docx");

?>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1> Social Return</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Schema_ID</th><th>Stakeholder_ID</th><th>Intended_Changes</th><th>Investment_Type_ID</th><th>Value_of_Investment</th><th>Summary</th><th>Outcomes_Description</th><th>Outcomes_Indicator</th><th>Outcomes_Source</th><th>Outcomes_Quantity</th><th>Outcomes_Duration</th>
        <th>Outcomes_Start</th><th>Outcomes_Financial_Proxy</th><th>Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy</th><th>Deadweight</th><th>Displacement</th><th>Attribution</th><th>Drop_Off</th><th>Impact</th>
        <th>Return_Year0</th><th>Return_Year1</th><th>Return_Year2</th><th>Return_Year3</th><th>Return_Year4</th><th>Return_Year5</th>
      </tr>
      <?php databaseOutput(); ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
<?php

  exit; // end of word output

}
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Social Return</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dunluce.infc.ulst.ac.uk/cw11ba/project/Project/mycss.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="export_form" action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="submit_docs" value="Export as MS Word" class="input-button" /> <a href="https://dunluce.infc.ulst.ac.uk/cw11ba/project/Project/admin.php"><button type="button" class= "btn btn-block">Go back to Admin Area</button></a>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="student">
      <tr>
        <th>Schema_ID</th><th>Stakeholder_ID</th><th>Intended_Changes</th><th>Investment_Type_ID</th><th>Value_of_Investment</th><th>Summary</th><th>Outcomes_Description</th><th>Outcomes_Indicator</th><th>Outcomes_Source</th><th>Outcomes_Quantity</th><th>Outcomes_Duration</th>
        <th>Outcomes_Start</th><th>Outcomes_Financial_Proxy</th><th>Outcomes_Value_of_Proxy</th><th>Deadweight</th><th>Displacement</th><th>Attribution</th><th>Drop_Off</th><th>Impact</th>
        <th>Return_Year0</th><th>Return_Year1</th><th>Return_Year2</th><th>Return_Year3</th><th>Return_Year4</th><th>Return_Year5</th>
          </tr>
      <?php databaseOutput(); ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want it to generate it like the word document attached below, also how can I add the image into the code so it can show exactly like that

[how I want the code generating the document to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ito9C.jpg)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to utilise a library like phpword

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText(
    $dbRow['Return_Year1']
    . $dbRow['Return_Year2']
);
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('myDocument.docx');
```

Comment: How can I do that on the server please? I know how to do it on a local server but not on 1 and 1 where I am hosting it. thanks